# Handling margins for a grid of elements with Lobotomized Owl

Tags: css

The [lobotomized owl](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls) tecnique is cool for a vertical list of elements (say a stacked list of cards, on mobile) but how to use it for a grid of elements (say 3 cards per row, on desktop)?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 1</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 2</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 3</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 4</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 5</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

.row > * + * {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Check the codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxxoMR
(in the example I placed 5 cards but obviously the project is dynamic so I don't know how many cards there will be)

You see that when the cards are stacked it works well but when I have more cards per row it doesn't: *Card 2* and *Card 3* have margin-top, while they don't have to get it.

How do you handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Simply consider `margin-bottom` for all the cards and consider negative margin on the main container:

```css
.row > * {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

/*styling*/
span {
  background: #ddd;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 1</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 2</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 3</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 4</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>Card 5</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>next row</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>next row</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"><span>next row</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I have to use the lobotomized owl tecnique (which uses `* + *` and margin-top). Using margin-bottom generates some issues on my layout.

Comment: @FredK as you can see the technique you are using isn't good that's why I provided another one. Why *you have to use* it ? there is no reason to be obliged to use a technique. Share your full use case and show us the issue you are facing (based on your actual code there is no issue)

Comment: With your solution Card 4 has margin-bottom, that is useless and add a margin I don't need. Obviously in the example I placed 5 cards but the project is dynamic so you don't know how many cards there will be.

Comment: @FredK check the upate, we can easily remove that margin

Comment: Temani, your solution could works but I specifically asked how to solve with lobotomized owl. Also, using negative margin is not an elegant solution. Your solution looks more like a workaround.